# How to use for loop for Map?

Tags: apex

This is code :

```
    count=10;    
    for (Integer idx=0; idx<count; idx++){
    qliw.comments__c='teja'+count;
    qouteLineItemMap.put(count,qliw);
    }
   quoteLineItemMapsize=qouteLineItemMap.size();
```

In this code it is not iterating .it just showing one value teja10.
I want this to be iterated teja1--------------------teja10.

How can i do that

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your code, you mean

```
qouteLineItemMap.put(idx,qliw); //key should be idx, not count
```

otherwise you just replace the same key 10 times over, as the value of count is always 10.

Comment: Thanks it works fine .But the value for comment shows me teja10 for all ten

Comment: The value of count is 10, and nothing in your code changes that - so qliw.comments__c='teja'+count; will always give you teja10   maybe you mean to have qliw.comments__c='teja'+idx;